# Black bars on bootstrap modal (Android chrome)

Tags: android, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I'm getting black "bars" on I open modal's on android's chrome, as show on my attachments, well, this is my code, and I'm using bootstrap 4.1. Anyone can help me?.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalCombos" tabindex="-100" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Combos</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                @foreach (var item in combosList)
                                {
                                <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5px">
                                    <div class="btn btn-danger col-12" onclick="addItem('@item.Nome', '@item.Valor.ToString("F")')">
                                        @item.Nome - R$ @item.Valor.ToString("F")
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: And for clarification, it only happens at Chrome, in other mobile browser, it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Change `.fade.in` opacity property on `bootstrap.min.css` from 1 to 0.99:

```
.fade.in{opacity:0.99}
```

Also try this on `bootstrap.min.css`:

```
.fade.in{opacity:1;-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;}
```

Comment: @FabricyoFigueira What's your Chrome version? Is it updated? please test with last version.

Comment: Yes, it's the last version.

Comment: So, nothing changed until now, I don't what else to do.